# Java/Python Cross-Compiling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, python, cross-compiling

I am working on a project that involves having a Java code editor and a Python code editor but I have no way of compiling that code. I've used Ace within my html and I have no idea how to compile the Java code or Python code using JavaScript. I currently have a way of retrieving all of the Java/Python code to a string. From there I need a way of compiling that code so that I can run it on my website and test it. There will be no GUIs involved, all of the Java/Python code will just have console output. However, I need a way I can run the Java/Python code on my website in live speed. Everything must be done on the website, the client shouldn't have to download anything extra. I am basically trying to replicate the website 'codingbat.com'. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python would usually get JITted when you invoke a good Python interpreter (ha, the name does not apply). Java has some great compilers (standard javac or the [Eclipse JDT](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/)) so I would not even think of compiling with some other language.

Where does the need come from to cross-compile in JavaScript? It sounds like you are searching for a Java compiler implemented in JavaScript, and likewise for Python.

If everything has to be built and deployed to some website, why don't you create a script (shell, JavaScript, or a Jenkins Pipeline) that compiles the java part using javac, precompiles the python part as required and deploys the output directly to your website?